# c# winforms gridview and selection boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, checkbox

I have a winforms c# app that displays tabular data from a DB into a gridview control.

I need to programmatically add a final column with a tickbox for each row, in order to find out which rows have been ticked form the current view.

How to go about doing something like that, as the tickbox column does not exist in the DB?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using the DataGridView for WinForms not the GridView on ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the extra column directly to your datasource before binding to the DataGridView.
Supposing that you are using a DataTable then

```
 DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
 dc.DefaultValue = false;
 grid.DataSource = dt;
```

Another method is define a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn() and append to the current column list

```
 checkCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
 checkCol.HeaderText = "Select";     
 checkCol.Width = 80;
 checkCol.ReadOnly = false;         
 grid.Columns.Add(checkCol);
```